# Apache POI extremely slow when exporting Runnable Jar with Package option in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi

I have performance problems with Apache POI when reading excel files when I export the runnable jar with the Package option  from eclipse, not with the Extract required libraries into generated JAR option.

In order to show you the problem, I have created a minimal program. The build.gradle file is:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
     compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.1.2'
}
```

and the  App.java file :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class App {

     public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final String excelPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/libro.xlsx"  ;
        try {
            final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(excelPath));
            
            
            final long TIMER = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(  "start") ;
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook( fis );
            wb.close();
            System.out.println( "end : " + ( System.currentTimeMillis() - TIMER) + " msec" ) ;
            
            
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error " + e.getMessage()) ; 
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program with an empty excel file, I get the following results on the same machine and with the same files:

- Generated with the Extract option:

  ```
     C:\temp>java -jar prueba.jar
     start
     end : 603 msec
  ```
- Generated with the Package option:

  ```
    C:\temp>java -jar prueba.jar
    start
    end : 6015 msec
  ```

about 10 times more.

What could it be the problem and how can I fix it so that the execution times are similar?

Could anyone help me to find the problem and solve it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the difference between the two files using `jar tf` followed by the archive. It may be that one of the archives is including the signed content, which will mean that upon load, the JVM will verify that the content is the same. You could perhaps see if there is a similar execution time when running with `-Xverify:none`, although I'd recommend against doing that in a production system.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed both files are very different.  The execution times with -Xverify:none are still similar to the execution without -Xverify none in each case: on the order of  600 ms with Extract option and 6000 ms with Package option.

Comment: Is there anything obviously different in the content of your files as reported by `jar tf`? Are the sizes of the files significantly different?

Comment: Sizes:  with Extract: 1098KB, (1517lines)  with Package 1Kb ( 23 lines). 
Extract:
`META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
App.class
org/
org/apache/
org/apache/poi/
org/apache/poi/ooxml/
org/apache/poi/ooxml/POIXMLDocument.class
...
........`

Package:
`META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
org/
org/eclipse/
org/eclipse/jdt/
org/eclipse/jdt/internal/
org/eclipse/jdt/internal/jarinjarloader/
lerFactory.class
.....
.....
App.class
poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar
poi-4.1.2.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar
commons-compress-1.19.jar
.....
.....`

Comment: It looks like one mechanism embeds your dependencies as jars, while the other expands the packages. You might find that the JarInJarLoader is being used and at runtime extracts all the files to another location on disk — I’ve seen similar delays using other mechanisms. Perhaps it extracts them to a temp folder or a hidden folder in your user root or where you are running it from?

Comment: I only use Eclipse IDE 2020-09 to make the jar file.
When I run de app into the IDE the execution time is normal (fast).
However when I export: File->Export ->Java Runnable JAR File -> option Package required libraries->Finish

and I run the jar file, the execution time is about 10 times than inside the IDE or exporting with the option Extract.   

I don't do anything manually to generate the jar file. This is the strange thing.

Comment: The manifest file in the Package option ( slow) is:
`Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar poi-4.1.2.jar poi-ooxml-schemas-
 4.1.2.jar commons-compress-1.19.jar curvesapi-1.06.jar commons-codec-1.
 13.jar commons-collections4-4.4.jar commons-math3-3.6.1.jar SparseBitSe
 t-1.2.jar xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar
Rsrc-Main-Class: App
Class-Path: .`

Comment: I have not seen either temporary or hidden files where I run the program

Comment: Just because you haven’t seen them doesn’t mean they aren’t there :-) but the difference in speed is due to the way that you have a resulting package (jar of jars) And it takes more time to unpack and load them. This will be a one of cost — one the classes are loaded the performance should be the same — but if you don’t want that then don’t select the package dependencies option in eclipse.

Comment: Thank you.
I get it; but the performance afterwards  (read, write....) is just as bad as at the beginning.
It is the only  dependencie with which this has happened to me.